# Using tokens or variables in Views "No Result Text" field

Tags: 7, views

How can I include a variable or token as a replacement in views "No Results Text"?

I would like to have information from the currently logged in users account populate this section when it would have otherwise been empty.

I would also like to access the second argument passed in the URL as replacement text.

`example/values/passed/to/views`

How can I use `arg(2)` as replacement text in views?

Here is how I'm hoping to use the UID:

[image: What I'm hoping to accomplish]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, in that field you should be able to use only [fields and arguments](http://drupalcode.org/project/views.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/handlers/views_handler_field.inc#l1212) tokens provide by Views only.

Unfortunately you can't use regular tokens  on that field. Maybe you should ask this directely on that [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1245524) your request to add support of tokens (that make sense actually).